# How to vertically align text Blocks on the left in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, angular-dart

I am trying to align three `Text()` on the left side of the page. These texts are inside `Padding()` blocks and these inside a `Column()`.

Here is how it looks:

[image: Screen shot]

And here is the code:

```
Column(
  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
  children: <Widget>[
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 78),
      child: Text(
        'Matches',
        style: TextStyle(
          color: Colors.white,
          fontSize: 44,
          fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
        ),
      ),
    ),
    Padding(
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
      child: Text(
        'Today\'s Live Matches',
        style: TextStyle(
            color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
      ),
    ),
    Column(
      mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
      children: <Widget>[
        Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
          child: Text(
            'LIVE MATCH',
            style: TextStyle(
                color: Colors.white,
                fontSize: 12,
                fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
          ),
        )
      ],
    )
  ],
)
```

Comment: crossAxisAlignment

Answer (score 1):

### To align Text

Refering to: [Text class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Text-class.html)

The `Text widget` has a `textAlign` property.

just add

```
textAlign = TextAlign.left
```

to your `Text` widget

Refer [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-ui/TextAlign-class.html) for more `textAlign` options

---

### To align column

Refering to: [Column class](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Column-class.html)

The column has a `crossAxisAlignment` property which is default to **center**

add

```
crossAxisAlignment = CrossAxisAlignment.start
```

to your `Column` widget

Refer [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CrossAxisAlignment-class.html) for more `crossAxisAlignment` options

Answer (score 0):

Try this

crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start